# XSL match xsl:variable element and change @select attribute

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to copy a complete xsl-file but change the specific value of the `@select` attribute of a specific variable.

My pseudocode idea:

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="variable[@name='Name']">
        <xsl:attribute name="select">
            <xsl:value-of select="'new value'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
```

To be perfectly clear; how do I select the variable element in a match statement?

It might be possible with `[CDATA]` but i prefer a more functional solution.

I am constricted to xslt 1.0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I select the variable element

Like any other element that's in a namespace, you select it by its [qualified name](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#dt-qualname), i.e. a name that includes a prefix bound to the element's namespace and its local name - for example:

```
<xsl:template match="xsl:variable[@name='Name']/@select">
    <xsl:attribute name="select">new value</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that your attempt, even if it did work, would remove the `name` attribute.

Comment: Aha. Thanks for both pointers.